# How to access JFrame Input field Objects from Validation Class

Tags: java, swing, validation, jframe

I have created a GUI with the registration field (firstname, lastname, email etc.) and my GUI class is -

```
public class Registration extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Registration regform = new Registration ();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            //
        }

      public Registration () {
            firstName = new JTextField();
            latName = new JTextField();
            btnRegistration = newJButton("Register");

            btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                  //want to do something similar as below
                  //Validatefields Vf = new Validatefields(Registration Rg);
             }
            });

       }
}
```

Now I want to create a separate class to Validate all the fields on clicking on "Register" button. I am new with Java coding and I am not able to access all the input fields Object of Registration class from Validation Class.

**please note Class Registration and Validatefields are under same package.**

```
public Class Validatefields{
    public static void Validattion(Registration Rg){
      //here I want access the text field as below
      //String Name = "Object of Registration Class".firstName.getText();

        
        int validateFlag = 0;
        if(Name.equal("")){
          validateFlag = 1;
        }
        if(validateFlag==0){
            ApiCall APC = new ApiCall();
            APC.RequestAccessToken();
        }
   }
}
```

in the next steps I want to use another class to call API on successfull validation - so in this method I would be require to get all input fields value.

```
public Class ApiCall {
   public static void RequestAccessToken(){
      //Similarly I want to get the individual field value here and pass it in the API
   }
}
```

I tried to read similar example from different source from internet but not able to figure it out. any help would be really great.

Comment: *"I tried to read similar example from different source from internet but not able to figure it out."* List the best 3 and why they did not help. SO is not a personal help desk, and it would help people to help you if they knew more about what you do not understand. Otherwise they're playing '20 questions' which is generally seen as a pointless and tiresome exercise.

Comment: Pro tip: be sure the code you post here is correct and exactly the same as what you are actually using. For example `public Class ApiCall` causes a compiler error.

Comment: "please note Class Registration and Validatefields are under same package." It would be much clearer to just show the `package` statement directly in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I want to create a separate class to Validate all the fields on clicking on "Register" button.

This is a very good idea and you have the general approach. I think the main problem is that you don't quite have the correct syntax. But before we get to that, my suggestion is that you pass the **fields** to the constructor instead of the entire `Registration` object:

```
public static void Validattion(JTextField firstName, JTextField lastName){
```

Now you create an instance by passing the fields to the constructor:

```
Validatefields Vf = new Validatefields(firstName, lastName);
```

Note that you only use the variable names here, not the types. This is most likely the main problem that you encountered and caused an error in your attempt.

Comment: Thank you Code-Apprentice; I was thinking instead of passing each individual field in the Validate function, if I can pass the object directly and then access the require fields from the object, because list of parameters in Validate function will be a long list.

Comment: @user1235994 That sounds like a reasonable alternative. Then you probably don't need to pass any parameters to the constructor. You should consider separate validation functions like `validateFirstName()` and `validateLastName()`. These might not be the best examples, but it is easy to imagine some groups of fields have different validation rules and so need a separate validation function.

Comment: @user1235994 So the key concept here is the last sentence in my answer, and most likely the problem you encountered in your own attempts: when you call a function, just specify the variables' names for the parameters, don't include the types.